# How to brace treehouse wall?

Tags: framing

I am adding wind braces to a treehouse I am building to provide extra strength. I’m trying to determine the best layout for the diagonal braces. Is one better than the other? A “V” shape, an upside down “V” shape, or two “K” shapes? See photos.[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I suggest that prior to bracing or sheeting, consider a larger window...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Triangles are good. Bigger triangles are better. Any/all of those are good, using both of the first two being delightful. We like X's.

However, IF using "modern materials" sheet goods have **many triangles contained in their rectangle.** So OSB or Plywood correctly fastened took a lot of old-style diagonal braces out of common framing...

If you are using boards as siding, by all means brace as much as possible within the constraints of allowing your window to exist.

One other "modern material" option is to use galvanized pipe-hanger strapping flat against the face of the framing - it's not thick enough to affect the boards going on, and has excellent tensile strength.